# Find missing element in in dictionary from relative hashset

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm beginner in C#.. I'm in a situation where I have a dictionary of

```
var enteries = new Dictionary<int, Entry>();
```

and I'm iterating over it by

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Entry> entry in enteries)
```

I have a `hashset<int>` that has all keys like 1,2,3. Sometimes the dictionary is missing a key, how would I know if the current key that I'm iterating of over in the dictionary is missing from the hashset ?

Basically I'm trying to write CVS file and I need to know if if there is key is missing, so that I can write some empty row for that id. 
I also want things to be sorted..

Looks like there is a misunderstanding:

```
Suppose enteries have keys, 238, 260 
hashset has 238,260,250
```

How would I relate when I iterate over each key,pair in the dictionary, that there is a missing element, which is 250, and I should output something for example.

Comment: Check `yourHashSet.Contains(entry.Key)`?

Comment: @cdhowie would you see the edit please ?

Comment: @andre I see.  My answer will work for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest code won't be the most efficient, but will work; union the set of keys together and then iterate that:

```
foreach (int key in enteries.Keys.Union(yourHashSet)) {
    Entry entry;
    if (enteries.TryGetValue(key, out entry)) {
        // The key is in the dictionary; the entry variable contains the value.
    } else {
        // The key is not in the dictionary.
    }
}
```

If you want to sort the keys, just apply this operation after the union:

```
foreach (int key in enteries.Keys.Union(yourHashSet).OrderBy(i => i)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

> how would I know if the current key that I'm iterating of over in the
>   dictionary is missing from the hashset ?

Assuming you've got a `HashSet<int> hashSet` instance you could use the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx) method to determine whether an integer value is contained within this hashset and act accordingly:

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = ...

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Entry> entry in enteries)
{
    if (hashSet.Contains(entry.Key))
    {
        // The current key is contained within the hashSet
    }
    else 
    {
        // The current key is not contained within the hashSet
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the reverse action. the hashset has all the keys that should be there, but the dictionary can have a missing key out of the hashset.

Comment: Then simply loop through the keys of the hashset and [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)on the dictionary by using the current key.

Answer (score 0):

Change your point of view.
As I understand in your HashSet is every needed Key. So iterate through the HashSet and find the key to every HashSet-Entry in the Dictionary.

Comment: you got me, would you elaborate some code?